# encounter issue that reloading view after changing its frame size

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

`message` property occupies whole screen. the app allows taking a photo. after taking a photo `img` becomes not `nil` and add the image to UIImageView.

then changing the `message`'s frame size and adding UIImageView to viewcontroller.

The UIImageView can be added successfully as i expected. But the `message`'s frame size doesn't change.

If i don't add this UIImageView, then, I can change `message`'s frame size.

How can I fix this problem?

I did try putting this code in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`, the code still doesn't work.

thanks.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var message: UITextView!
    var img: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            if img != nil {
                let imageview = UIImageView(image: img)
                let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.4
                let y = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - height
                imageview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: height)
                message.frame = CGRect(x: message.frame.origin.x, y: message.frame.origin.y, width: message.frame.width, height: message.frame.height - height)
                self.view.addSubview(imageview)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes. I did use. But if I don't add a subview. I can change the size of message view. For example, I can make a button to change message view's size. But if I add, I can't change message view's size.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using autolayout than you should take outlet of your height constraint of your message textview and you should reduce it's constant by height instead of resetting it's frame because frame will not affect when you have set constraints! If you have not set the height constraint then take outlet of bottom constraint of your text view and change the constant with height size instead of zero! You can drag and drop from constraint to your class to take its outlet!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. And I can change the height of message textview if I don't add the subview. Example:  add this code in viewdidappear: message.frame = CGRect(x: message.frame.origin.x, y: message.frame.origin.y, width: message.frame.width, height: message.frame.height - height) without adding subview. The message textview the size will be changed.

Comment: thanks. you are fight. but so hard to find solution. but i found on my new book. using this line message.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageview.topAnchor).isActive = true